# git rebase strange behavior

Tags: git, rebase

I have strange git rebase behavior for next example.
Suppose, I have the local tree:

```
                     ∨
           b1--b2--b3                      
          /
a1--a2--a3
```

and the remote tree

```
            b1--b2--b3
          /
a1--a2--a3--a4--a5--a6
```

where the branch a is master

and at the current time, I am being at the b3.
I call the next commands:

```
git pull origin master master // fixed typo
git rebase master
```

after this actions I have the tree, that look like:

```
          a4'--a5'--a6'--b1--b2--b3                
         /
a1--a2--a3--a4--a5--a6
```

instead

```
                       b1--b2--b3
                      / 
a1--a2--a3--a4--a5--a6
```

Why does it occur?

Comment: i think "git rebase origin/master" will fix your problem.    or adding "--rebase" option to "git pull" so that it becomes "git pull --rebase".   The problem is that you are doing a "git pull" which bring in a merge commit (when necessary) to your local master, and then you are rebasing against that.

Comment: I assume `git pull origin mastert master` is a typo / cut-and-paste error, and that you meant `git pull origin master`. I also assume you were on some branch other than your own local `master` when you ran `git pull`.

Comment: No, I did `git pull origin master master`

Comment: That's still slightly (and importantly) different than what is in your question.

Comment: Yes, I know how to fix my problem, but I don't understand why does it occur.

Comment: Why did this question get -1'd?,  it's a perfectly good question with example and description of what the OP attempted and the result they got. I find that people are too strict on SO these days, quick to -1 everything unless its perfect and quick to vote close - its not very constructive. So +1 because its a decent question and to counter the -1 : )

Comment: "git pull origin master master" is the same as "git pull origin master" (the 2nd master is irrelevant).  Well, almost the same.  The auto-generated commit message for the merge commit will be slightly different, but that's just cosmetic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always advise people to avoid `git pull` until they are very familiar with Git, as it does too much, in a somewhat mysterious way, that is hard to explain.  It's often (and reasonably accurately) described as equivalent to running `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase`, but the tricky part is that the arguments it passes to `git merge` or `git rebase` are not what you might expect.

That said, let's break these down and look closely at each step.  I will also draw your commit graph a bit differently.  (You call this a "tree" above, which is not the best terminology for two reasons.  First, the commit graph is a *graph*, specifically a **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or DAG.  All trees are DAGs, but not all DAGs are trees.  Second, Git uses the term *tree* to refer to "tree objects"; each commit carries a tree object.)

Your initial commit graph looks, I believe, like this:

```
           B1--B2--B3   <-- branch (HEAD)
          /
A1--A2--A3   <-- master, origin/master
```

Note that your local branch-name `master` points to commit `A3`.  Your remote-tracking branch name `origin/master` also points to commit `A3`.  Your current branch, however, is named `branch` (I had to invent this name) and it points to commit `B3`.

You now run `git pull origin master master`, or perhaps `git pull origin mastert master` (it matters which of these you use, and your comment contradicts your question).  This `git pull` command runs `git fetch` with a number of arguments.

#### The `git fetch` step obtains new commits

Whenever you run `git fetch`, including when you use `git pull` to run `git fetch`, your Git calls up another Git, probably at the URL stored under your remote name `origin`.  Here—as run by `git pul origin master master` or perhaps `git pull origin mastert master`—this other Git has delivered several new commits.  Your Git stores these new commits in your repository, and if your Git is at least version 1.8.2, your Git updates your `origin/master` (and maybe your `origin/mastert`) to point to these new commits.

Your Git also stores in the special file `FETCH_HEAD` the IDs of the new commits and the name(s) of the branch head(s) obtained from the remote.  Hence we can add this to the graph drawing:

```
           B1--B2--B3   <-- branch (HEAD)
          /
A1--A2--A3   <-- master
          \
           A4--A5--A6   <-- origin/master, FETCH_HEAD
```

What's in `FETCH_HEAD` is a bit tricky.  The contents of this file include the original names, i.e., `master` and perhaps `mastert`, as seen on the *other* Git, without any of the `origin/` renaming that your Git normally uses.  There may be some lines for tags too.  Some of these lines may also be annotated with `not-for-merge`.  All of the lines contain hash IDs for specific Git objects (commits and sometimes tags).  The `git fetch` program leaves these lines specifically for the `git pull` program to examine.

Next, your `git pull` command extracts from `FETCH_HEAD` the hash IDs of the newly obtained commits.  That is, it searches through `FETCH_HEAD` for hash IDs for commits that are *not* labeled `not-for-merge`.  (I assume here you are doing a merge style pull rather than a rebase style pull.)  It then runs `git merge` with these hash IDs.

#### The `git merge` step makes a merge commit

Again, it matters now whether you ran `git pull origin master master` or `git pull origin mastert master`.  If you ran the latter, and there was  branch named `mastert`, there will be *two* matching lines, and perhaps two different hash IDs.  In this case, your `git pull` command will perform an *octopus merge* of these two hashes.

If not, you will get a normal merge of the one hash.  I am going to assume you get a normal merge.  The result is this:

```
           B1--B2--B3------M   <-- branch (HEAD)
          /               /
A1--A2--A3   <-- master  /
          \             /
           A4--A5-----A6   <-- origin/master, FETCH_HEAD
```

Note that your branch name `master` still points to commit `A3`, not to commit `A6`.

You now run `git rebase master`.

#### Rebase strips off merges

What `git rebase` does is that it *copies* commits.  The commits it copies are those you specify.  The destination for the new copies is also something you specify.

When you run:

```
git rebase master
```

you are telling Git to copy any commits that are on your *current branch* (i.e., `branch`) that are *not* reachable from your branch named `master`, and that are not merge commits (you will copy commits reachable *from* the merges, but not the merges themselves).  Note that this is not using `origin/master`, but `master`.  Hence the commits you ask your Git to copy are `B1`, `B2`, and `B3`, and `A4`, `A5`, and `A6` ... in some order (the actual order somewhat difficult to predict, though the A and B groups will be copied together, as Git uses `--topo-order` when collecting the IDs of commits to copy).

The place you ask your Git to copy them is "after the tip of `master`", i.e., after `A3`.

If Git copies `B1` first, it will generally retain `B1` unchanged, because `git rebase` will do that if it can.  If it copies `A4` first, it could also try to retain `A4` unchanged, for the same reason; but the mechanism that does this is foiled by this particular rebase (see comments below).  Once Git has copied `A4` through `A6`, it *must* copy `B1` to a new commit whose parent is the `A6'` copy of `A6` (this commit differs from the original `B1` as `B1`'s parent is `A3`).

(You can, however, force `git rebase` to copy anyway, e.g., with `--no-ff` or `--force`.)

Your outcome suggests that your Git chose to copy `A4` first.  This gives you:

```
           A4'-A5'-A6'-B1'-B2'-B3'  <-- branch
          /
A1--A2--A3   <-- master
          \
           A4--A5--A6   <-- origin/master
```

Without `--force` or `--no-ff`, if `git rebase` were slightly smarter, it could (but doesn't) produce:

```
A1--A2--A3   <-- master
          \
           A4--A5--A6   <-- origin/master
                     \
                      B1'-B2'-B3'  <-- branch (HEAD)
```

or (can and sometimes does) produce:

```
           B1--B2--B3--A4'-A5'-A6'   <-- branch (HEAD)
          /
A1--A2--A3   <-- master
          \
           A4--A5--A6   <-- origin/master
```

Comment: I also prefer "git fetch" but I'm sad that it cache-busts all my remote branches, making the "--force-with-lease" option on git push pointless.

Comment: @G.SylvieDavies: you can run `git fetch origin br1:origin/br1` (and, since 1.8.2, leave out the `:origin/br1` part) but admittedly by this point it's really close to just resorting to `git pull` directly :-) It turns out there are some weird interactions with tag fetching as well: tags only get updated if you name an explicit local reference (such as the remote-tracking branch above, the `:origin/br1` part).

Comment: It has to copy a4 rather than use it in-place, because nothing like a4 is present on (local) master (a3).   Try for yourself:   http://vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/plugins/servlet/bb_net/projects/BB/repos/so-44795166/commits    (git clone; git checkout b; git pull origin master; git rebase master; git log --all --date-order --graph --decorate)

Comment: The logic for this mechanism is really interesting, "it will generally retain B1 unchanged, because git rebase will do that if it can".  Here's the info from "git help rebase":   "Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in HEAD..<upstream> are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped)."   I suspect it's running "git patch-id" to implement that logic.

Comment: @G.SylvieDavies: Aha, right, the reuse-instead-of-copy code path requires that the rebase code *see* the commit here (which it doesn't). It's not literally running `git patch-id`, but it is the same code: it uses `git rev-list` with the symmetric difference notation and the various `--cherry` options.